# Why Instagram GET request return "405 Method not allowed"?

Tags: android, instagram

I can easily GET data through the following request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=my_access_token
```

using my web browser. And all data is correct.
But when I trying to request using Android

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
cn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
cn.setDoInput(true);
cn.setDoOutput(true);
cn.setRequestProperty("access_token", my_access_token );
cn.setRequestMethod("GET");
cn.connect();
```

I getting "405 Method not allowed" response. Why? How to access Instagram API through the Android.
Also I want to note that access token is getting well in same manner but with method POST and some output message (as described in manual), so I am sure that my_access_token is correct and up to date.

Best Regards
Ekaterina

Comment: You mean "method not allowed"? If so, either your access token is wrong or you are using a deprecated API call

Comment: access token is correct, and I do not understand why this api can be outdated since it is mentioned https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Comment: Hmm, alright. Maybe use a different User-Agent for your HTTP call?

Comment: In FireFox exactly that GET works. But 405 form Android device

Comment: A different user agent doesn't mean use a browser. A user-agent is an HTTP header you can set in your code. I suggest you look up how to add headers to the HttpsURLConnection

Comment: It doesn't work! I have made this way: cn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0");
And got the same response "405 method not allowed"

Comment: Hmm. Worth a shot... If you use a private/incognito browser on Firefox/chrome can you still successfully access that api with your token?

Comment: Yes it does work this way. So?

Comment: Just wanted to see if there was something with cookies in the browser letting you access it... I'm out of ideas, sorry

Comment: Ok I will pay attention to the cookies. I just want to tell , when I getting access_token like described here http://b2cloud.com.au/uncategorized/instagram-integration-in-an-android-app/ everything works perfect. The differences are POST method instead of GET and outputStreamWriter.write outputStreamWriter.flush instead of cn.connect() so I am surprised ....